# Having trouble with app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app.yaml

Basically my directory layout looks something like this:

```
- demo
|
+ + exmaple1
| |
| + index.html
| + some-script.js
|
+ + example2
...
```

What I want to achieve is to make it such that

```
my.url/demo/example1                 shows  /demo/example1/index.html
my.url/demo/example1/some-script.js  shows  /demo/example1/some-script.js
my.url/demo/example1/index.html      redirects to  my.url/demo/example1
```

Here is my app.yaml:

```
handlers:
# some stuff here
- url: /demo/([^/]+)$
  static_files: demo/\1/index.html
  upload: demo/(.+)/index\.html$

- url: /demo
  static_dir: demo
```

It does return the correct page for `my.url/demo/example1`, but when I try to request `my.url/demo/example1/some-script.js`, it returns 404. Why is that and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a handler for the .js file.  And by "redirect", do you mean a full 301 redirect, or just to show the `index.html` static file?
  Does this do what you need?

```
- url: /demo/(.*)/(.*)
  static_files: demo/\1/\2
  upload: demo/(.*)/(.*)

- url: /demo/(.*)
  static_files: demo/\1/index.html
  upload: demo/(.*)/index.html
```

Comment: By redirect I meant a 301 redirect. The directories might contain nested directories so your approach will probably not work. Upon doing some reading apparently I can't use `static_dir` with `static_files`, so I ended up creating a handler to manage all this.

Comment: What you are calling "directories" in the path are not necessarily directories, as they were in the old days.  Your app.yaml can parse that and point anywhere.  Examples: `/a/b/c/d/e/f` can point to `/1/`.  `/g` can point to `/1/2/3/4/5/6/`.  The only difference is that in my answer, the visitor doesn't get redirected, and still sees `my.url/demo/example1/index.html` as the url in the browser.